# Can't write closing square bracket

Tags: qgis, python

I am unable to write the closing square bracket in QGIS Python console or editor, unless automatic parentheses insertion is enabled. Parenthesis and curly brackets work fine. Keyboard layout is Spanish. Happens only in QGIS. Tried two different computers. Is this a bug or what is going on? Basically, I can't type " ] " in QGIS Python

Comment: try (right alt +) .....  http://kbd-intl.narod.ru/english/layouts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's explained in https://issues.qgis.org/issues/21203:

"removing 'Zoom In' ('Configuración'->'Atajos de teclado...->'Acercar zoom' in Spanish version) keyboard shortcut gets the ']' symbol back!"